# Cannot find Default weight and Dimension - NopCommerce

Tags: nopcommerce-4.0

After upgrading from NOPCommerce 3.90 to 4.0, I now get the following warnings:

```
Default weight. The ratio should be set to 1. 
Default dimension. The ratio should be set to 1.
```

I cannot find them anywhere in the settings and have searched the NOPCommerce online documentation.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check shipping's [measure setting](http://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/Admin/Measure/List) "Ratio to primary weight" and "Ratio to primary dimension" should be 1